# using a pandas dataframe to test for multiple "IF", "AND, "ELIF" conditions and execute code based on the result?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'condition1': ['ON', 'OFF', 'ON'], 
                   'condition2': [10, 15, 20],
                   'condition3' : ['OFF', 'ON', 'OFF']})
```

Output:

```
  condition1  condition2 condition3
0         ON          10        OFF
1        OFF          15         ON
2         ON          20        OFF
```

Now lets say, I would like to execute "`print('Hello World')`" IF 'condition1'  is 'ON', 'condition2' is > 15,  and 'condition3' is 'OFF'.

So based on the dataframe above 'Hello World' Would be printed when the 3rd row is evaluated as the set criteria have been fulfilled.

Please recommend a way to achieve the above goal, and provide a code snippet to demonstrate the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First is [best forget for looping in `apply` or `for`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-not-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code/54432584#54432584), because vectorized solutions exist:

```
#create mask
m = (df['condition1'] == 'ON') & (df['condition2'] > 15) & (df['condition3'] == 'OFF')

#if need new column
df['new'] = np.where(m, 'Hello World', '')
print (df)
  condition1  condition2 condition3          new
0         ON          10        OFF             
1        OFF          15         ON             
2         ON          20        OFF  Hello World
```

If need execute `print ('Hello World')` if exist in dataframe use:

```
if m.any():
    print ('Hello World')
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. If I just simply would like to execute 'print('Hello World') without creating a new column as soon as the desired condition is fulfilled then how would I do that?

Comment: @LucasSchwartz - Answer was edited.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` on `row` like below: *(this approach slower than vectorize like another answer)*

```
def prt(row):
    if row['condition1'] == 'ON' \
    and row['condition2'] > 15 \
    and row['condition3'] == 'OFF':
        return ('Hello World!')
    return ''
df.apply(lambda row: prt(row),axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0                
1                
2    Hello World!
dtype: object
```

If you want to print if any row meets conditions you can try this:

```
def prt(row):
    if row['condition1'] == 'ON' \
    and row['condition2'] > 15 \
    and row['condition3'] == 'OFF':
        return True
    return False
chk = df.apply(lambda row: prt(row),axis=1)
if chk.any():
    print('Hello world')
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-not-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code/54432584#54432584)

Comment: @jezrael I definitely approve vectorize is better but is good OP see all approach in future maybe he can decide for all problem use vectorized or apply If I don't post this answer this conversion never exist.

Comment: ya, it is most problem of people starting with pandas - using apply if not necessary like here. So No problem if post solution, but always necessary warning - dont use it, because slow, not vectorized...

Comment: why use vectorize solution in future and not today?